# How can I deny Windows10 get thumbnails from thumbcache_idx.db?

Tags: windows, thumbnails

I am trying to deny Windows store APP Photos to open pictures in Win10. I hooked Windows API CreateFileW so that I can deny some files opened. But for Photos, I found that even returned INVALID handle in CreateFileW, it can still extract thumbnail from Win10 thumbcache_xx.db. 
I've known that Windows map the picture's thumbnail according thumbcache_idx.db. Is there any way to interact with this process, so I can deny Photos get thumbnail according thumbcache_idx.db?

Comment: open the database in exclusive mode?

Comment: @Marichyasana but it will deny the other process do read the database